# What are the principal upanishads according to different Vedanta sects?

Tags: advaita, vedanta, vishishtadvaita, dvaita, achintya-bheda-abheda

I was wondering whether different Vedanta sects (Advaita, Vishishtadvaita, Dvaita, Dvaitadvaita, Achintya-bhedabhed-vada, shuddhadvaita and Akshar-purushottama) agree on the number of principal Upanishads and their names. They disagree on various issues. I am not sure whether they agree on this.

As far as I know, Adi guru Shankaracharya (Advaita) wrote commentaries on 8 Upanishads, which are the principal Upanishads in Advaita school. Did Acharyas from other schools write commentaries on exactly those Upanishads? or have they included or excluded some items in their list?

I have seen books containing 10 principal Upanishads, 13 principal Upanishads etc. Is there any standardized number?

Comment: All the Vedānta darśanas accept the daśopaniṣats and hold them as having foremost importance. However, after 10, these darśanas vary.